# Enemy Shoot Closest Object Within Shooting Range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I would like the Enemy(Monster) to shoot players in Shooting Range of the Enemy and return closest players within the Range
I'm quite new to Unity and currently using Unity 2017,2D at the moment, for now.
Thanks so much for your Help Guys!

public class Monster : MonoBehaviour {

```
[SerializeField]
GameObject Bullet;

public float fireRate;
float nextFire;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    fireRate = 1f;
    nextFire = Time.time;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    CheckIfTimeToFire ();
}

void CheckIfTimeToFire()
{
    if (Time.time > nextFire) 
    {
        Instantiate (Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
    }
    
}
```

}

Here is the Bullet Script

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float moveSpeed = 3f;

Rigidbody2D rb;

PlayerAI target;

Vector2 moveDirection;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    target = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerAI>();
    moveDirection = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2 (moveDirection.x, moveDirection.y);
    Destroy (this.gameObject, 2);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name.Equals ("Player")) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Hit!");
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for posting code but it's not really relevant to your question - maybe show what you've tried on this. Anyway you want https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html to detect other colliders in a radius i.e. the collider on your player in a radius from the enemy

Comment: So is your question "How get all Players?" in general .. or rather "How to filter them by distance?" .. or "How to get the closest object from a list?" ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a small number of players, a convenient method would be to hold a reference to players as a collection and iterate to get `transform.position` of each player. Then you can check the distance to the monster to get the minimum distance.

I also suggest doing the logical check on Monster rather than on Bullet, and pass target to Bullet. So that you can choose not to instantiate a bullet if no player is in range.

```
public class Monster : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public float range;

    private PlayerAI[] players;
    
    ...

    private void Awake()
    {
        players = FindObjectsOfType<PlayerAI>();
    }

    ...

    private void CheckIfTimeToFire()
    {
        if (Time.time < nextFire)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        PlayerAI closestPlayer = null;
        float closestPlayerDistance = float.MaxValue;

        foreach (PlayerAI player in players)
        {
            float playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);

            if (playerDistance > range ||
                playerDistance > closestPlayerDistance)
            {
                // Skip to next player.
                continue;
            }
            
            closestPlayer = player;
            closestPlayerDistance = playerDistance;
        }

        if (closestPlayer == null)
        {
            // No player in range. Do nothing.
            return;
        }
            
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate (Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().Initialize(closestPlayer.transform);
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
    }

    ...
}

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    private Transform target;

    ...
    
    public void Initialize(Transform target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }
    
    ...
}
```

In the example, I get the players on `Awake()` of a Monster, but if you are instantiating them in runtime you can hold the `PlayerAI` collection in a separate manager class. In this case a list could be more useful.

```
public void PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<PlayerAI> Players { get; private set; }
    
    ...

    private void Awake()
    {
        while (playerCount < totalPlayerCount)
        {
            SpawnPlayer();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        PlayerAI player = Instantiate(player, ...);
        Players.Add(player);
    }

    // Remove a dead player, etc.
    private void OnPlayerDied(PlayerAI player)
    {
        Players.Remove(player);
    }

    ...
}

public class Monster : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    private PlayerManager playerManager;
    
    ...

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerManager = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>();
    }

    void CheckIfTimeToFire()
    {
        ...

        foreach (PlayerAI player in playerManager.Players)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```